# VM1052:19 Error: (SystemJS) TypeScript transpilation failed

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular2-template

- I am new to angular, I am trying to change color for each li when I click it.
- but I am getting an error VM1052:19 Error: (SystemJS) TypeScript transpilation failed
- can you guys tell me how to fix it.
- providng code below

http://plnkr.co/edit/npNw39aRZVgpqEjI6uLH?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts&p=preview

```or-tag-here
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styles: [`
    li {
      color: red;
    }
  `],
  template: `<ul class= "master">
                <li *ngFor ="let student of liArraycontent" (click) = "liClicked($event)"> {{student}} </li>
              </ul>`
})
export class AppComponent { 
  name = 'Angular';
  liArraycontent = ["testing 1", "testing 2", "testing3"]

  liClicked = function(e1) {
    console.log(e1.target);
    e1.addCss(color: green);
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add style attribute.

add this line in you click event:

```
e1.target.setAttribute("style", "color: green;");
```

link to working plnkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/w1i9v1fJ02htbDrtkWUy?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts&p=preview

Comment: code is not working...can you tell me how to fix it :(

Answer (score 0):

Writing random code and seeing if it works is probably not the best way to learn Angular. Instead, you should read the tutorials and guides. The easiest way in your specific case is to add a `style` property to the template:

```
// template
<ul class= "master">
  <li 
    *ngFor ="let student of liArraycontent; let i = index" 
    (click)="liClicked(i)" 
    [style.color]="colors[i]">
    {{student}}
   </li>
 </ul>

// component
color: 'blue';

liClicked(index) { this.colors[index] = 'green'; }
```

Here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/tRZoZe3KU41hiQEfXUad?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts&p=preview).

In terms of your original code:

1. The event handler will be passed an event, not an element. If you really wanted to get the element from the event, you need `event.target`.
2. I'm not aware of any `setCss` method on elements.
3. The syntax `setCss(color: green)` is invalid. `key: value` pairs occur within object literals. If there were a `setCss` method, which there is not, it would likely be called as `setCss({color: 'green'})`, where `green` is a string and therefore needs to be quoted; otherwise it would be interpreted as a variable.
4. In correct Angular style, you do not manipulate DOM elements yourself, whether to set styles on them or for anything else. Instead, you write your templates so that component properties, such as `color` in the above code, are used to drive element behavior, using attributes such as `[style.color]`.

Comment: hello I tried but still not working :( http://plnkr.co/edit/wxciw6MAhvqcQhbEulfV?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts&p=preview